# Valgrind C++ memory leaks

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have this demonstrable piece of code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    int ** matrix = NULL;
    int c = 1, input = 0;

    printf("Enter first row of the matrix:\n");
    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        input = fgetc(stdin);

        matrix = (int**) realloc(matrix, 1 * sizeof (int*));
        if (matrix == NULL) {
            printf("Troubles with memory allocation!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        matrix[0] = (int *) realloc(matrix[0], c * sizeof (int));
        matrix[0][c-1] = (int) input;

        c++;
    }

    free(matrix[0]);
    free(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

This is causing in Valgrind an error, but I really don't know what does that mean and how to fix it... could anyone give me an advice?

```
==30031== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==30031== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==30031==    at 0x402868B: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==30031==    by 0x80485CB: main (main.cpp:17)
==30031==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==30031==    at 0x402860A: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==30031==    by 0x4028694: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==30031==    by 0x80485A6: main (main.cpp:12)
```

Comment: You haven't initialized matrix[0] before your second realloc call. It could be filled with anything.

Comment: BTW, consider using STL containers, `std::vector<int>` being most logical choice. No realloc, no hassle.

Comment: If it is 2-dimensional array, with which value it should be filled in?

Comment: The functionality of `realloc` depends on the value of the first parameter. In your case it has to be NULL, or otherwise it will crash.

Comment: your 2-dimensional array is actually `(pointer to (malloc-ated array of (pointer to an (malloc-ated array of int))))`; so you should fill them with NULLs; however take @Dialecticus's advice and save yourself some trouble by using vector

Comment: If this isn't only demo code but something you've considered: creating matrices as arrays of arrays is a bad idea. The implementation troubles are already demonstrated, but it's also size wise (1*n additional pointers) and performance wise (indirections) a bad choice over one one continuous region of memory where you calculate the position of the element (e.g.: pos = row*columns+col). On the other hand: there are very good matrix libraries available that do that for you with much consideration of effectiveness like eigen2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`matrix[0] = (int *) realloc(matrix[0], c * sizeof (int));`

You are passing `matrix[0]` as a parameter without initializing it beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use more powerfull utility. 
BoundsChecker, Deleaker, XWatcher...

Comment: your link is broken

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to use [deleaker](http://www.deleaker.com) - a powerful tool for debugging memory leaks!

Comment: I have added a link to the software for you, welcome to the site z0r1fan!